# Azure pipeline, upload build report

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am automation tester who is testing web app, currently my azure pipeline workflow looks like this:

1. build web app (docker)
2. run my automation testing (it runs in docker container as well)

Now, it works fine, however after my automation testing is finished, it is generating html test report, now here is a tricky part, how do I extract it from container that is run in azure pipeline.

If I run it locally, I can mount volume and share docker container volume with host, I was thinking about writing small program, that would be run after test report is generated, that uploads it to some server, but is there better approach?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a Private agent (not Hosted) and use the volume

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files out of a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run --name ci orgName/ci`

Assuming `docker run` generates a file called `TestResults.xml` in the root of the container, you can then copy it out:

`docker cp ci:/TestResults.xml ./TestResults.xml`

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am not exactly sure I fully understand it though, where would file be copied to in my case when container is run in azure pipeline?

Comment: @MateuszMysliwiec The file would be copied to the agent, at which time you can do whatever you need to do with it, such as publish it as an artifact.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel - it make sense